# Whats the extension for mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

Ok so after building my code there are two files created the source code in .cpp for c++ and the exec which runs on the terminal ,i uploaded the exec file onto forums to share it to other mac users but after downloading the exec file it cant run at all on the terminal,is there an extension that should be included eg- project.exe that should make it run on the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the file (let us assume it is called `foo`) has been downloaded it won't have the executable bits set:

```
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 f.nas users 2111 Sep 13 10:07 foo
$ # Set executable bits
$ chmod +x foo
$ ls -l foo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 f.nas users 2111 Sep 13 10:07 foo
$ # Now we can run it.
$ ./foo
This is the foo program
$
```

Also, don't forget that the current directory (`.`) is not usually in the PATH, so you need to use `./` to specify the pathname of the program.

Comment: @F.NAS:  If this was helpful to you, please "accept" the answer by clicking on the tick mark, and vote for the answer by clicking the upward pointing triangle above the answer score.  (By doing this, you help indicate which are good answers, and which bad.)

Comment: oh right sorry about that it was helpful.